How to force a Jetpack Compose Desktop text to display █ with full height and width of the "text cell"
I'm trying to achieve a similar effect like in terminal, where █ looks like a space with filled background.
My current code looks like this:
@Composable
fun myComposable(){

    val res = "██\n ██"
    Text(
        text = res,
        style = TextStyle(letterSpacing = 0.sp, lineHeight = (height - 3).dp.textDpToSp(LocalDensity.current)),
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
        fontSize = TEXT_SIZE_SP
    )
}

 fun Dp.textDpToSp(density: Density): TextUnit = with(density) {
    this@textDpToSp.toSp()
}


I've tried following apporaches with a on Ubuntu:

setting text spacing to 0.sp ( but there are still very thin spaces)
reducing the height slightly, but the effect isn't scalable for other text sizes.

